# Zip and apply a list of functions over a list of values in Python

Tags: python

Is there idiomatic and/or elegant Python for zipping **and applying** a list of functions over a list of values?

For example, suppose you have a list of functions:

```
functions = [int, unicode, float, lambda x: '~' + x + '~']
```

and a list of values:

```
values = ['33', '\xc3\xa4', '3.14', 'flange']
```

Is there a way to apply the ith function to the ith value and return a list of the same length of the transformed values, while avoiding this ugly list comprehension?

```
[functions[i](values[i]) for i in range(len(functions))] # <- ugly
```

What I want is something like `zip()` + `map()` (`zipmap()`!) the functions list with the values list and have the functions be applied to their paired values. I thought `itertools` might offer something relevant, but functions like `imap` and `starmap` are for mapping a single function over an iterable, not an iterable of functions over another iterable.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that the task you are desiring is kind of ugly itself, so one should expect the implementation to be - as you judge it - ugly also.

Comment: @msw I think the task is rather common -- think of transforming raw bytestrings to Python objects from a CSV file or similar, so the list of functions could come from a column mapping that carries other metadata like the column data, etc.

Comment: @msw: Stick your head inside an average database and see how ugly a database can grow when nobody's bothered to write some ugly code to validate it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

These solutions seem overly complicated:  `map` already zips its arguments:

```
map(lambda x,y:x(y), functions, values)
```

Or, if you prefer the iterator version:

```
from itertools import imap
imap(lambda x,y:x(y), functions, values)
```

Comment: +1 for the mapping form of zip.  Python's built-in ``apply`` function is broken and deprecated, but it's easy to fix: ``apply_ = lambda f, *args, **kwds: f(*args, **kwds)``.  With that, you can just say ``map(apply_, functions, values)``.

Answer (score 26):

```
[x(y) for x, y in zip(functions, values)]
```

Comment: To be honest, I was hoping for a non-list comprehension-based solution, no matter how elegant, and yours certainly is -- I was holding out for a functional application solution, preferably from the standard library. But yours is pratical, concise, and not ugly :)

Comment: Right -- I guess I meant, a pure function application as opposed to syntax. But point taken :)

Comment: @Paul Smith, one of the reasons that this sort of thing doesn't need to be covered by the standard library is that python has list comprehensions. They're an integral part of the language and should be used where appropriate. They're appropriate here.

Comment: I don't want to imply that I somehow eschew list comprehensions, only that I was seeking a different, itertools-inspired approach in this case. All glory to list comprehensions!

Comment: "and not ugly :)" If you think this solution is ugly, then you think that python is ugly.  this strikes me as very pythonic

Comment: If you don't want a list, you can use a generator, which is pretty much the same thing: `(x(y) for x, y in itertools.izip(functions, values))`

Comment: This is OK except for choice of variable names -- wouldn't `[f(x) for f,x in zip(functions, values)]` have been a little prettier? ;-)

Comment: One thing that `map` does in Python 2 (but not 3), it interprets `None` as the equality function, i.e. the value is not transformed. This can be added to this solution with `[f(x) if f else x for f, x in zip(functions, values)]`.

Answer (score 4):

One of the beautiful features of functional encapsulation is they can hide ugliness.

If you need `zipmap`, define it:

```
def zipmap(values, functions):
    return [functions[i](values[i]) for i in range(
      len(functions))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Code that is meant to function robustly would do this in a for loop so that it could provide meaningful error reporting:

```
for i in xrange(num_columns):
    try:
        outrow.append(functions[i](input_values[i])
    except (ValueError, EtcetcError) as e:
        self.do_error_reporting(row_number, i, input_value[i], e)
        outrow.append(None)
```