# list of functions and function args

Tags: python

I was wonder about the performance about some of the options for zipmap described in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231345/zip-and-apply-a-list-of-functions-over-a-list-of-values-in-python).

(I'm still new here, so I couldn't comment on that thread).

In particular, I'm interested in comparing the list comprehension:

```
[f(x) for f,x in zip(functions, values)]
```

to the map call:

```
map(lambda f,x: f(x), functions, values)
```

I've heard the lambda is expensive, but won't map involve fewer function calls?

Thanks!

Comment: "lambda is expensive" is nonsense.

Comment: What CatPlusPlus said, plus how about testing it yourself? http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html

Comment: @CatPlusPlus *Relatively* expensive. Time and time again tests will show you that a list comprehension will outperform `map()` if you use `lambda` with the map.

Comment: thanks for the pointer to the timeit library!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, readability over performance - unless you can prove that this is a bottleneck for your program, go with the far more readable list comprehension.

If it *is* a bottleneck, then do some performance tests (see [the `timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html)) - but unless all the functions are trivial, it'll probably not matter much either way.

Doing a quick test:

```
python -m timeit -s "functions = [lambda x: x+y for y in range(1000)]" -s "values = list(range(1000))" "[f(x) for f,x in zip(functions, values)]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 207 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "functions = [lambda x: x+y for y in range(1000)]" -s "values = list(range(1000))" "list(map(lambda f,x: f(x), functions, values))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 315 usec per loop
```

And if you wanted a generator expression:

```
python -m timeit -s "functions = [lambda x: x+y for y in range(1000)]" -s "values = list(range(1000))" "list(f(x) for f,x in zip(functions, values))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 250 usec per loop
```

And using Python 2.x's old-style map which produces a list straight away for completeness (equivalent to the list comprehension example):

```
python2 -m timeit -s "functions = [lambda x: x+y for y in range(1000)]" -s "values = list(range(1000))" "map(lambda f,x: f(x), functions, values)"  
1000 loops, best of 3: 234 usec per loop
```

We can see that the list comprehension wins on performance anyway.