# Apply a different Python function to corresponding element

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I would like to know if there is a built-in numpy (i.e., efficient) way to apply a vector of functions to a vector of values, such that each function takes in a corresponding value (almost like a dot product for input values to functions). An example in pseudocode:

```
[func1, func2, func3, ..., funcn] x [val1, val2, val3, ..., valn] 
= [func1(val1), func2(val2), func3(val3), ..., funcn(valn)].
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

There is another question along similar lines as this one, but this one specifically asks whether there is a more efficient way than just iterating over the lists, whereas the other question is more focused on the elegance of the code itself.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231345/zip-and-apply-a-list-of-functions-over-a-list-of-values-in-python? Although the answers are not in numpy way.

Comment: Thanks, checked it out. Do you know how efficient that is? Also see my comment to the answer by radeklos below

Comment: I presume you want to end up with a numpy array?

Comment: Can you give some examples for your functions? If they're all from the same family (e.g. polynomials) and only differ in some numbers then it might be possible to vectorize them.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, preferably, yes.

Comment: @swenzel that's a good idea, but unfortunately they could be from any family

Comment: what are you starting with numpy arrays or lists?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham numpy arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
results = map((lambda (f, v): f(v)), zip(functions, values))
```

But zipping and then mapping won't be faster than just iterating over the indexes of both lists and applying the function to the value:

```
results = []
for i in range(len(functions)):
    results.append(functions[i](values[i]))
```

**Testing**

*zipmap.py*

```
def add1(x):
  return x + 1

vs = range(100000)
fs = [add1] * 100000

results = map((lambda (f, v): f(v)), zip(fs, vs))

> time python zipmap.py
> 
> real    0m0.153s 
> user    0m0.127s     
> sys     0m0.023s
```

*forloop.py*

```
def add1(x):
  return x + 1

vs = range(100000)
fs = [add1] * 100000

results = []
for i in range(len(fs)):
    results.append(fs[i](vs[i]))

> time python forloop.py
>
> real    0m0.155s
> user    0m0.073s
> sys     0m0.030s
```

I don't know how much quicker for loops is to be honest, python interpreter probably does fancy optimizations.

Comment: why not just use enumerate? Also if you want to time python code use timeit

Comment: @PadraicCunningham timeit looks great, hadn't heard of it! Enumerate is probably a more *pythonic* way of doing it, yes

Comment: If you have ipython, it is as simple as `timeit  your_func` https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function to merge two list and then call the function item to values item.

```
zip([f1, f1], [v1, v2]) -> ((f1, v1), (f2, v2))
```

Comment: How efficient would that be? I started using numpy recently for its efficiency, but I am thinking of maybe writing a C function for this, then calling it from Python

Comment: Or better `izip` in Python 2