# Is it possible to unpack values into several functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to unpack elements in python and pass them directly into several functions without assigning them into a variable first?
e. g.

```
def my_function():
    return (1, 2)

# Not sure how the syntax would look like?
(function_1(#first element here), function_2(#second element here)) <= my_function()
```

Comment: what you ask is not clear

Comment: This seems to be a (near) duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231345/zip-and-apply-a-list-of-functions-over-a-list-of-values-in-python

Comment: This answer in particular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4231350/1467943

Comment: It's a bad code smell to squeeze many calls in a single line.

Comment: @PiotrRarus The idea was to unpack the return value of a function and append those values to different lists. While thinking about that I came up with the question. There was not supposed to be actual programming logic via several function calls in a single line

Comment: @ales_t Edit: Yeah, you are right. That does answer my question. If you type it out as an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, to not assign your output to any variable, for example by calling the function twice, which theoretically would make only sense if the function is a pure function. However I do not find any useful example. I am curious why you would like to do it.

Comment: See my comment under the question with reference to Piotr. Assigning values to different lists would be an example, no?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way around achieving that goal.
This, it would require you to create your own method that does that.

Here is a simple approach of how you might want to do that.
In my example, there is a function called `dissolve_args_to_fns` which accepts functions and a `list` that hold values to the functions input.

**`dissolve_args_to_fns` implementation**

```
from typing import Tuple, Any
from collections.abc import Iterable

def dissolve_args_to_fns(*fns, inputs: Tuple[Any, ...]):
    # If there are more inputs than there are functions, and vice-versa, throw error
    if len(fns) != len(inputs):
        raise ValueError('The numbers of functions dont match the number of inputs each function')

    # Holds the output corresponding to each function
    outputs = []
    for i, fn in enumerate(fns):
        # Individual input for each function
        inp = inputs[i]

        # Checks if the input for the function is an iterable
        # If so, then its probably for an argument that need multiple arguments
        if isinstance(inp, Iterable) :
            fn_out = fn(*inp)
        else:
            fn_out = fn(inp)

        outputs.append(fn_out)

    # returns an output if, there is any function that has an output
    # This extra checking step is not necessary
    if any(map(lambda x: x is not None, outputs)):
        return outputs
```

Now that the function is done, we can begin testing it out.
Below, are 3 custom functions, some of which have an output, and others which don't

```
def show(value):
    print("Here is", value)

def blink(value, blink_count:int = 2):
    print(f" *blink* {value}" *  blink_count)

def full_name(first_name, last_name) -> str:
    return "%s %s" % (first_name, last_name)
```

I'll also be using the `sum` in-built function to show how wide this implementation can be used

```
_, name, _, _sum = dissolve_args_to_fn(show, full_name, blink, sum, inputs=(1, 2, ("Mike", "Tyson"), ([10, 5],)))

print("My name is", name)
print("Sum is:", _sum)
```

Well that's it. This simple function now works like magic.

Happy coding.

PS: As you can see, the simple implementation doesn't work for keyword arguments, but feel free to hack the code as a you please

Answer (score 0):

The following is to the effect of what you described in your further comments:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []


def my_function():
    return (1, 2)


def function_1(x1):
    list1.append(x1)


def function_2(x2):
    list2.append(x2)


lam = lambda x: (function_1(x[0]), function_2(x[1]))
lam(my_function())
```

Verification:

```
>>> print(list1)
[1]
>>> print(list2)
[2]
```