# map with function for each element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, variable-assignment, iterable-unpacking

Very often I process single elements of tuples like this:

```
size, duration, name = some_external_function()
size = int(size)
duration = float(duration)
name = name.strip().lower()
```

If `some_external_function` would return some equally typed tuple I could use `map` in order to have a (more functional) closed expression:

```
size, duration, name = map(magic, some_external_function())
```

Is there something like an *element wise* `map`? Something I could run like this:

```
size, duration, name = map2((int, float, strip), some_external_function())
```

**Update**: I know I can use comprehension together with `zip`, e.g.

```
size, duration, name = [f(v) for f, v in zip(
   (int, float, str.strip), some_external_function())]
```

-- I'm looking for a 'pythonic' (best: built-in) solution!

**To the Python developers**:

What about

```
(size)int, (duration)float, (name)str.strip = some_external_function()
```

?
If I see this in any upcoming Python version, I'll send you a beer :)

Comment: I would think a custom class that *models your data* would make sense here, instead of treating values individually. That class could also care about casting arguments to their correct types, which I might do as an alternative constructor like `foo = SomeExternalData.from_string(*some_external_function()); print(foo.size)`…

Comment: I'd say, the whole point of [`map`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) (as a concept in functional programming) is to apply _one_ function to _each_ element of the list. So, your `map2` won't really be a "true" `map` then.

Comment: you're right - my point is not to use `map` but to have a readable, short closed expression in the end without states, intermediate variables or re-assigning variables. `map` is just a way to show what I mean.

Comment: long time ago I've implemented this kind of utility in [`lz` package](https://lz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lz.html#lz.functional.combine), if you don't want extra dependency I can write a recipe as an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zip and apply a list of functions over a list of values in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231345/zip-and-apply-a-list-of-functions-over-a-list-of-values-in-python)

Comment: The answer in the question you posted is the same, yes. The semantic is different since my goal is not to apply a list of functions but to somehow modify the tuple unpacking on assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map does not really apply here. It comes in handy when you want to apply a simple function over all elements of a list, such as `map(float, list_ints)`.

There isn't one explicit *built-in* function to do this. However, a way to simplify your approach and avoid `n` separate calls to the functions to be applied, could be to define an iterable containing the functions, and apply them to the returned *non-unpacked* tuple from the function on a generator comprehension and *then* unpack them:

```
funcs = int, float, lambda x: x.strip().lower()
t = 1., 2, 'Some String  ' # example returned tuple

size, duration, name = (f(i) for f,i in zip(funcs, t))
```

Or perhaps a little cleaner:

```
def transform(t, funcs):
    return (f(i) for f,i in zip(funcs, t))

size, duration, name = transform(t, funcs)
```

---

```
size
# 1
duration
# 2.0
name
# 'some string'
```

Comment: `(size)int, (duration)float, (name)str.strip = some_external_function()` (i.e. 'reciprocal' functions) is what should exist in my eyes :). Since it doesn't, your answer seems to fit my intentions

Answer (score 6):

Quite simply: use a function and [args unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)...

```
def transform(size, duration, name):
    return int(size), float(duration), name.strip().lower()

# if you don't know what the `*` does then follow the link above...    
size, name, duration = transform(*some_external_function())
```

Dead simple, perfectly readable and testable.

Comment: Your answer - in my eyes - shows how it should be done if you plan to re-use `transform`. If I could select two answers, yours would be one of them. In my scenario I have several transformations to do - each different from the other, so a one-liner like `size, name, duration = transform((int, float, str.strip), some_external_function()` is more what I need now.

Comment: It actually doesn't have much to do with reuse - that's typically what I do even for one-shot scripts. Trying to be generic for the sake of being generic is ibn my experience mostly a waste of time. Now it of course, once again, depends on the context and concrete use case, so only you can tell which approach fits your current needs best ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
class SomeExternalData:
    def __init__(self, size: int, duration: float, name: str):
        self.size = size
        self.duration = duration
        self.name = name.strip().lower()

    @classmethod
    def from_strings(cls, size, duration, name):
        return cls(int(size), float(duration), name)


data = SomeExternalData.from_strings(*some_external_function())
```

It's far from a one-liner, but it's the most declarative, readable, reusable and maintainable approach to this problem IMO. *Model* your data explicitly instead of treating individual values ad hoc.

Comment: Well... depends on your use case, really. I would certainly do something similar if those were really domain model stuff, but definitly not for a simple parsing where those data will be actually used to build or update or query existing domain model objects ;-)

Comment: "Some external function" which returns strings sounds like an external API of some sort, and IMO it makes sense to model that as its own thing. It makes it easier to write adapter code that turns that external format into some internal format. If you don't model what format your external data source uses and just always treat it ad hoc, that makes long term maintenance that much harder, especially if you use it a lot.

Comment: might just be reading a csv file to update a database for what we know - as I said, it really depends on the context, which we don't have. Note that I upvoted your answer FWIW - I'm not disagreeing on the advice, just mentionning that depending on your real use case it can be either the RightThing(tm) or just plain overkill.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no built-in solution so we can write generic function ourselves and reuse it afterwards

```py
def map2(functions, arguments):  # or some other name
    return (function(argument) for function, argument in zip(functions, arguments))  # we can also return `tuple` here for example
```

The possible problem can be that number of arguments can be less than number of functions or vice versa, but in your case it shouldn't be a problem.
After that

```py
size, duration, name = map2((int, float, str.strip), some_external_function())
```

We can go further with [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and give a name to our "transformer" like

```py
from functools import partial
...
transform = partial(map2, (int, float, str.strip))
```

and reuse it in other places as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Bruno's transform, which I think is the best answer to the problem, I wanted to see if I could make a generic transform function that did not need a hardcoded set of formatters, but could take any number of elements, given a matching number of formatters.

(This is really overkill, unless you need a large number of such magic mappers or if you need to generate them dynamically.)

Here I am using Python 3.6's guaranteed dictionary order to "unpack" the formatters in their declared order and separate them from `inputs` variadic.

```
def transform(*inputs, **tranformer):
    return [f(val) for val, f in zip(inputs, tranformer.values())]

size, duration, name = transform(*some_external_function(), f1=int, f2=float, f3=str.lower)
```

And to make the process even more generic and allow predefined transform functions you can use `operator.partial`.

```
from functools import partial

def prep(f_tranformer, *format_funcs):
    formatters = {"f%d"%ix : func for ix, func in enumerate(format_funcs)} 
    return partial(transform, **formatters)


transform2 = prep(transform, int, float, str.lower)
```

which you can use as:

```
size, duration, name = transform2(*some_external_function())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll second bruno's answer as being my preferred choice. I guess it will depend on how often you are calling this function will determine how much value it is in refactoring such a hindrance. If you were going to be calling that external function multiple times, you could also consider decorating it:

```
from functools import wraps

def type_wrangler(func):
    def wrangler():
        n,s,d = func()
        return str(n), int(s), float(d)
    return wrangler


def external_func():
    return 'a_name', '10', '5.6'

f = type_wrangler(external_func)

print(f())
```